# Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<GenderStatistics> but Class<TypeVariable(T)!>! was expected

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, quarkus-panache

I am trying to build [Query Projection](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-projection) and I have encountered the following error message:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<GenderStatistics> but Class<TypeVariable(T)!>! was expected
```

the code that is causing the problem:

```
  fun status(): String {
    val query = accRepo.find("""
      select g.abbr as abbr, g.description as description, count(p) as quantity
        from Account a
        inner join a.gender as g
        group by g.abbr, g.description
      """.trimIndent())
        .project(GenderStatistics::class)
```

The method `project` expects type `Class<TypeVariable(T)!>!` but I have passed wrong type. How to pass the correct type in Kotlin? In Java, it will be `GenderStatistics.class`

The `GenderStatistics` is defined as:

```
@RegisterForReflection
class GenderStatistics(val abbr: String, val description: String, val quantity: Int)
```

Comment: does it work if you use `GenderStatistics::class.java` to pass the java Class instead of the kotlin KClass, or are there further issues even after doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try changing

```
GenderStatistics::class
```

to

```
GenderStatistics::class.java
```